# Determining if an extension was installed through Chrome Web Store or not

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I noticed that in chrome://extensions you can see a "Not from Chrome Web Store" message under extensions that were installed through, e.g. drag and drop into the extensions page. Screenshot of what I am talking about:

[image: Extensions page]

I was wondering if there is any way of getting that information from an extension API? I have played with the chrome.extensions.management API, but the only information that gives is the installType field, which is 'normal' for both Web Store and drag and drop installs. - https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#type-ExtensionInfo

Am I missing something, or will we just have to wait for an update to the management API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you simply check if the `updateUrl` property is equal to https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx? I believe extensions in the Chrome Web Store must have that update URL, but I'm not sure about the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Either you install by drag-and-drop or you install form web store, both are called normal install type. Ultimately, you are trying to install the .CRX file, so it means it's a normal install type. Here is the help [article](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#type-ExtensionInfo). Search for "installType" and read description for "normal" in mentioned article.

Comment: That does not answer the question; the question states _"the only information that gives is the installType field, which is 'normal' for both Web Store and drag and drop installs"_, and OP is aware of this properly and wants to differentiate those.

Comment: You can't differentiate those two behavior, there is no any way available for now.